# Python imports from the same folder doesn't work

Tags: python, import, module

I created a working folder: *C:\Users\robin\bayesian-optim*

Inside there are **module1_test.py** and **work.py**

I have some functions in module1_test.py that I want to use in work.py, but using `import module1_test as mmm` in the shell gives the following error :

```
ImportError: No module named 'dossier_module'
```

It is the first thing that I do not understand. To go further,
I tried this :

```
import sys  
sys.path.insert(0,'C:/Users/robin/bayesian-optim')
```

Then it worked, but my real goal is to clone some git codes in this folder and to call them instead of my example module1_test.py. When I do so, cloning "pymoo" in *C:\Users\robin\bayesian-optim*, I have the same problem :

```
  File "C:/Users/robin/bayesian-optim\pymoo\pymoo\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pymoo.version import __version__

ImportError: No module named 'pymoo.version'
```

All the .py folders inside of the cloned repo are not foundable, and it would mean that I would have to add at the beginning of every code "import sys, sys.path.insert(0, path/to/this/folder)". Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Assuming that just importing a module named `module1_test` cannot cause the error `No module named 'dossier_module'`, you'd probably have to add which modules `module1_test` is importing itself to recieve a helpful answer.
Do you have python in your path?

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I finally managed this by adding manually to my PYTHONPATH `C:/Users/robin/bayesian-optim`, this way I will not have to run `sys.path.append("path/to/module")`

Comment: This should not be necessary. You should not have to add every project-folder to your PATH to run your files. But we need more information to help you, as the problem cannot be reproduced with the details given.